# Is jupyter notebooks installed in Anaconda's base?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

I am trying to learn how to work with Jupyter Notebooks and Anaconda.

I was wondering whether Jupyter notebooks should be installed/ran from the base environment in Anaconda or from a self-created environment and why? I read that environments are used to manage Python versions en packages for projects but Jupyter notebooks seems to be something that is not project specific (I could be wrong here).

Disclaimer: I know Anaconda comes with Jupyter notebooks. My question is more aimed at correct use of it.

Comment: I think this is a matter of taste. I personally prefer having jupyter in base using `nb_conda_kernels` to make all environments with ipython kernels available in the jupyter interface. I find it convenient, others may disagree.

Comment: I concur. Generally, keeping a single instance of `jupyter` and co-installing `nb_conda_kernels` enables one to avoid having to reinstall (and manage) multiple Jupyter versions. Similar to @.cel, I follow the model in [the `nb_conda_kernels` docs](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda_kernels#nb_conda_kernels), but use a dedicated env, instead of **base** for the Jupyter infrastructure. Note that I use Miniconda, which does not include `jupyter` installed in **base** by default like Anaconda does.